# Using the Selected Item from Combo box in If Statement

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Basically i have a vending machine and the total price will be displayed in a Label. Now there is a combo box showing money for example 1.00 , 2.00 , 5.00 etc.

Now i want to check with an if statement weather the money that is chosen from the combo box is bigger or smaller from the total price.

the code is not working

```
if (cbMoney.SelectedItem < total)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Money");
}
```

ERROR Description :Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'double'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how do you guys know the total type?

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(cbMoney.SelectedItem.ToString()) < Convert.ToDouble(total))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Money");
}
```

Comment: The error  `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'double'` states that `total` is a double

Answer (score 2):

SelectedItem is an object and will need to be parsed.

```
if (double.Parse(cbMoney.SelectedItem.ToSTring()) < total)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Money");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need ToString() too

Answer (score 1):

you are taking the SelectedItem object and not converting before checking.

Try as below:

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(cbMoney.SelectedItem.ToString()) < total)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Money");
}
```